# Как сохранить токен?

Tags: java, android

Отсылатся запрос с imei телефона, в ответ выдается токен, при выходе и запуске приложения токен должен сохраняться.

Проблема в том , что токен временный и раз в час выдается новый.

Вот код который сохраняет полученный токен, но не обновляется новым. 
pastebin.com/vYsvs4kH

Как решить данную проблему ?

Comment: @metalurgus , как обновить его

Comment: @metalurgus , как обновить его

Comment: `как обновить его` кого?

Comment: @metalurgus обновить токен

Comment: точно так же, как и сохранить - перезаписать

Answer (score 1):

1. При использовании токена, если он устарел, сервер сообщит об этом.
2. В этот момент вам надо стереть старый токен
3. И сделать запрос на получение нового.
4. Получив новый, его надо снова записать.
5. Сразу после получения можно записать ещё и timeStamp до коего он будет валиден. Но это не поможет, если начать переводить часы/зоны, так что можно это не делать

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/551688/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5-retrofit