# Запрос в запросе retrofit

Tags: java, android

У меня есть запрос

```
 public void onResponse(Call<Count> call, Response<Count> response) {

                        Log.d("Response", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                        if (response.body().getmCount().equals("2")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "У вас осталось: " + response.body().getmCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        } else if (response.body().getmCount().equals("1")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "У вас осталось: " + response.body().getmCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        } else if (response.body().getmCount().equals("0")){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"У вас осталось: "+response.body().getmCount(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            mCount = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Count> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
```

Но у меня ошибка от сервера 401, при этой ошибке мне нужно отправить новый запрос, как это сделать?

Comment: мне кажется, вам нужно делать это в  `onFailure`, в зависимости от responce code

Comment: @metalurgus можете конкретный пример привести

Answer (score 2):

1. Создайте отдельный метод, в коий поместите запуск ретрофитом нужного запроса.
2. В случае ошибки или кода 401, как у вас, запускайте этот метод
3. Вызовите `return` чтобы не выполнять код далее